# Dependency Injector and Collections

Tags: dependency-injection, dependencies, collections

I have been searching for an answer in this topic but I haven’t been able to find a satisfactory one like in other topics, where the consensus is solid.

**The situation**

To keep things simple: I am implementing a custom Dependency Injection Container into one of my current projects (I know, I should use an already built one, but I’m doing it with learning purposes; so answers like ‘use this func of that container…’ are not useful) and I’ve stumbled a problem with instantiation of new elements inside a collection.

**The problem**

Imagine that I have a complex object, for example a car. This car has several dependencies (engine, axis, seats, airbags…) that have, at the same time, their own dependencies, and so on. It is not a big issue to make the DiC (via autowiring or using a config file) build the object graph and inject all the dependencies with a simple line of code like:

```
$car = $container->get(‘car’);
```

The problem arrives when I build a CarCollection, which is a simple class that wraps an array of cars. The issue comes when I try to use a method that populates the collection with all the cars that exist in the database. It’s obvios that the collection should be able to create the Car objects on the fly when we call the “getAll” method from the database. The code would be something like this:

```
public function populate(array $filters) {
    $all_data = $this->dao->getAll($filters); // Call the data access object to query all cars.
    foreach($all_data as $data) {
        $new_object = $this->container(‘car’); // create a template object
        $new_object->setData($data); // set the info.
        $this->items[] = $new_object; // Add to the collection.
     }
}
```

If car was not such a complex object it would be easier, because I could pass the car fqcn as a parameter for carCollection and use it in every iteration. But that’s not possible for a very complex object (or if I want to instantiate different sub types of the object - for example: lorry, pick-up, van…- depending on information from the database).

**The question.**

Regarding the collection being aware about the container: does not it break the purpose of the DIC phylosophy?

I guess not on one side, because I am using PSR\Container to type hint the container I pass to the collection (which loosens the coupling). But it breaks the idea that the container should not be coupled with the domain model at all.

The only alternative that I have thought about is substituting the creation of one new object for each iteration with a cloning from a prototype object that lives in the collection as a property. But we all know cloning in php can get really tricky and very difficult to debug (Or worse: very difficult to even know that there is a problem going on).

**Similar issue.**

PS: I have the same problem when I try to do lazy loading using Porxy objects: I need the proxy objects to have access to the container if I want to instantiate the full object later, which also breaks the principles of a DiC.

Thank you all.

Comment: Can't write a full answer right now, but let me just post a comment. In `populate`, you have `$new_object = $this->container(‘car’)` - now think about what's more likely: is it more likely that you'll replace `car` with something else, or that you'll replace `$this->dao` with a different data source (either because you're pulling from an alternate data source, or because you're mocking it for testing purposes)? If the latter, then `$this->container(‘car’)` is superfluous, just use new, it's *fine*; `populate` *should* be coupled to `car`, but not to the data source.

Comment: What I'm saying is, a DI container should support dependency injection, not be a replacement facility for object creation. In your example, you're not *really* injecting a car, nor a car factory, as a design decision; you are instead using the container as a globally accessible factory of car objects.

Comment: The problem with using "new" is that Car is very complex on its own, so I should instantiate all of its dependencies as well inside the CarCollection (which means I am coupling the collection with a lot of classes and not only the DIC).
An alternative would be injecting inside the collection a carFactory object, but I see no real difference between that and injecting the DIC (which already knows how to instantiate a car --> If I change car instantiation I would need to change it in the DIC and in the factory....